# actually what different new and object and how it run in ram

Tags: javascript, c#, oop, object

what is the difference between the object and new? cause in javascript when u code as below means was created an address at stack when having the new keyword.

```
     var a=new A();
     function A(){};
```

so in c# when I create like this it is the same concept as above or no?

```
        int x;
        Console.WriteLine("ENter value of N");
        x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        object y = x; //boxing 
        int z = (int)x; // unboxing 
        Console.WriteLine(z);
```

and what different in c# when I use new to create an address

```
        Form myForm = new Form(); //this can call boxing or no?
```

Comment: Don't try to compare javascript with c#. It's like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: JavaScript does not expose how the JavaScript engine uses memory. The assumption  that variables are stored on the stack  _is not generally true._

Comment: There is no unboxing on this line of code. `int z = (int)x;` x was never anything but an integer. I think you meant `int z = (int)y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should know that Javascript is a dynamic, weakly typed and scripting language and bind at runtime while C#(C Sharp) is a strongly typed static language and compiled in advance.

An object is an instance of the class that describe its behaviour. The class can be described as a blueprint or template for creating an object.

`new` is a keyword in C# that is used to create an object of the class and return its pointer or address. Then we use its pointer to access the object. The object is stored on heap and its pointer is returned for further use.

So in C# you can create an object by

```
Form objForm = new Form();
```

Plz read this for further understanding

> **Heap:**
>
> The heap is a block of memory in which objects (i.e., reference-type instances) reside. Whenever a new object is created, it is allocated on the heap, and a reference to that object is returned. During a program’s execution, the heap starts filling up as new objects are created. The runtime has a garbage collector that periodically deallocates objects from the heap, so your program does not run Out Of Memory. An object is eligible for deallocation as soon as it’s not referenced by anything that’s itself alive.